# Python: How to convert nested lists inside nested dicts into dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

so I have this dict:

```
di = {'Type': ['Something1'],
      'details': [{'detail': [{'category': ['Stuff1'], 'value': ['Value1']},
                              {'category': ['Stuff2'], 'value': ['Value2']},
                              {'category': ['Stuff3'], 'value': ['Value3']},
                              {'category': ['Stuff3'], 'value': ['Value3']},
                              {'category': ['Stuff4'], 'value': ['Value4']}]}],
      'timestamp': ['2018-01-22 07:10:41']}
```

and would like to convert any `list`, except for any `list of dicts` **not containing another `list of dicts`** inside them, to a `dict` so that the end result would be:

```
{'Type': 'Something1',
 'details': {'detail': [{'category': 'Stuff1', 'value': 'Value1'},
                        {'category': 'Stuff2', 'value': 'Value2'},
                        {'category': 'Stuff3', 'value': 'Value3'},
                        {'category': 'Stuff3', 'value': 'Value3'},
                        {'category': 'Stuff4', 'value': 'Value4'}]},
 'timestamp': '2018-01-22 07:10:41'}
```

So essentially, for any key whose value is a single item `list`, the value should drop the `list` component.

I've tried with the following recursive function without success:

```
def delistdict(dicto):

    delisted = {}

    for k,v in dicto.items():

        if isinstance(v, list) and len(v) == 1:  
            delisted[k] = v[0]

        else:
            delisted[k] = delistdict(v)

    return {k:v if len(v) == 1 else v for k,v in delisted.items()}
```

It fails because it only removes the first instance of the `list` in `{'detail': [(...)]` (so just that outer **[(...)]** list) but it doesn't recurse to the remaining items. So my result looks like this after running the script:

```
{'Type': 'Something1',
 'details': {'detail': [{'category': ['Stuff1'], 'value': ['Value1']},
                        {'category': ['Stuff2'], 'value': ['Value2']},
                        {'category': ['Stuff3'], 'value': ['Value3']},
                        {'category': ['Stuff3'], 'value': ['Value3']},
                        {'category': ['Stuff4'], 'value': ['Value4']}]},
 'timestamp': '2018-01-22 07:10:41'}
```

What should happen is that the single values inside the `value` and `category` keys should be converted to `string`s instead of remaining as single items within a `list`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If a value is a dict, then recursively apply your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
di = {'timestamp': ['2018-01-22 07:10:41'], 'Type': ['Something1'], 'details': [{'detail': [{'category': ['Stuff1'], 'value': ['Value1']}, {'category': ['Stuff2'], 'value': ['Value2']}, {'category': ['Stuff3'], 'value': ['Value3']}, {'category': ['Stuff3'], 'value': ['Value3']}, {'category': ['Stuff4'], 'value': ['Value4']}]}]}
def flatten(d):
  return {a:b[0] if len(b) == 1 and isinstance(b[0], str) else (flatten(b[0]) if len(b) == 1 and isinstance(b[0], dict) else [flatten(c) for c in b]) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'timestamp': '2018-01-22 07:10:41', 'Type': 'Something1', 'details': {'detail': [{'category': 'Stuff1', 'value': 'Value1'}, {'category': 'Stuff2', 'value': 'Value2'}, {'category': 'Stuff3', 'value': 'Value3'}, {'category': 'Stuff3', 'value': 'Value3'}, {'category': 'Stuff4', 'value': 'Value4'}]}}
```

Non-comprehension solution:

```
def flatten(d):
   new_d = {}
   for a, b in d.items():
      if len(b) == 1 and isinstance(b[0], str):
          new_d[a] = b[0]
      elif len(b) == 1 and isinstance(b[0], dict):
          new_d[a] = flatten(b[0])
      else:
          temp_list = []
          for c in b:
             temp_list.append(flatten(c))
          new_d[a] = temp_list
   return new_d
```

Output:

```
{'timestamp': '2018-01-22 07:10:41', 'Type': 'Something1', 'details': {'detail': [{'category': 'Stuff1', 'value': 'Value1'}, {'category': 'Stuff2', 'value': 'Value2'}, {'category': 'Stuff3', 'value': 'Value3'}, {'category': 'Stuff3', 'value': 'Value3'}, {'category': 'Stuff4', 'value': 'Value4'}]}}
```

Comment: so your solution works for the end "leaf" nodes but still leaves the condition unmet that any list with only one item inside should be dropped and only the inside item kept, even if this "one" item is a dict. For your result to be what I'm looking for the script should also drop that **[** that prefaces the first 'detail': `'details': [{'detail': [{'category': 'Stuff1', 'value': 'Value1'}`. I think you are headed in the right direction though!, would you be able to share the non-dict-comprehension version of it so I can understand better?

Comment: That's' nice and succinct, though if the data was not `str` type it could cause a stir.  The dict comprehension version is nutso!

Comment: @Ajax1234 you did it mate! the only reason I'm not selecting it as "the answer" is because, even when far better than my code, it's too complicated for my limited mind to understand as it is. If you would post it in like a fully fledged function with no "comprehensions" I would accept it. Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: @quassar glad to help! I removed all comprehensions from the "Non-comprehension" solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't spend the time to optimize the code, but I modified your original function to do the trick:

```
def delistdict(dicto):

    delisted = {}

    for k, v in dicto.items():

        if isinstance(v, list):
            lst = []
            for i in v:
                if isinstance(i, dict):
                    lst.append(delistdict(i))
                else:
                    lst.append(i)
            delisted[k] = lst[0] if len(lst) == 1 else lst
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            delisted[k] = delistdict(v)
        else:
            delisted[k] = v

    return {k:v if len(v) == 1 else v for k,v in delisted.items()}
```

## Output (pretty printed):

```
{'Type': 'Something1',
 'details': {'detail': [{'category': 'Stuff1', 'value': 'Value1'},
                        {'category': 'Stuff2', 'value': 'Value2'},
                        {'category': 'Stuff3', 'value': 'Value3'},
                        {'category': 'Stuff3', 'value': 'Value3'},
                        {'category': 'Stuff4', 'value': 'Value4'}]},
 'timestamp': '2018-01-22 07:10:41'}
```

The issue was your function assumed all `list` should have `len` 1, otherwise it just returns the delisted dictionary, which still have nested `list`s inside unprocessed.

Comment: thanks for showing where my error was mate, which was part of my question too, as I struggle to understand how recursive functions work. And as I go trying to understand your answer, I will accept it. Thanks! (couldn't upvote it because I don't have enough reputation sorry)

Comment: Thanks! I must admit @Ajax1234's code is more succinct and concise (both comprehension and non-comprehension version).  One tip I would give you though is look into the `pprint` module, it helps make your lists/dictionaries much more readable and helps debug, especially for lengthy and nested objects.

Comment: If you agree then I will select @Ajax1234 answer, but yours keeps being the one that helped me understand recursive functions the most ;)